# How to get data from a server using observable in angular 5 and typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular5

**Is Getting data from a server using observable the best practice?**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say observables are the "**best**", as that is very much subjective and depends on the exact situation, but I WOULD say that they encourage **best practices**, especially explicit state management, which is very important if you want your app to have predictable, and thus easily debuggable, behavior.

In a small project? Potentially more overhead than necessary, depending on how fast you want to just be done with it. In a large project with many (and potentially concurrent) web requests, though? Observables become very useful and lead to a much better developer experience than anything else.